# Kotlin: iterate through array in reversed order

Tags: kotlin

Is there a convenient way in Kotlin to iterate through an array, let's say `IntArray`, in reversed order with these 2 conditions:

- do not create an additional reversed copy of the array.
- I need a handle to an element like in Java's enhanced `for`.

The best I could get is adding an extension function, but this needs to be done for each type of array if I need it not only for `IntArray`s:

```
fun IntArray.forEachReversed(action: (Int) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (i in indices.reversed()) action(this[i])
}
```

Is there a better way in Kotlin class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this needs to be done for each type of array if I need it not only for IntArrays:

I think this is unavoidable because of the way the JVM works. There are separate classes to represent each primitive type on the JVM. However, there are only 8 of them, so it shouldn't be too bad ;-)

For Collections, there is the [`asReversed()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html) function, but it's not available for arrays:

> ```
> val original = mutableListOf('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
> val originalReadOnly = original as List<Char>
>     val reversed = originalReadOnly.asReversed()
>
> println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e]
> println(reversed) // [e, d, c, b, a]
>
> // changing the original list affects its reversed view
> original.add('f')
> println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
> println(reversed) // [f, e, d, c, b, a]
> ```

Comment: `asReversed` doesn't create a copy? Don't have access to IDE to check right now.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/ReversedViews.kt), it uses a reversed copy of the indices.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip From what I can tell, it doesn't copy anything; it simply inverts each index that's passed into its functions (e.g., in an array of 5 elements, 0 to 4, an index of 1 would become 3).

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, you solution looks fine but if your are targeting primitive `IntArray`, `LongArray`, `FloatArray` etc you cannot come with a generic solution, as this classes are independent and only thing common is `Iterator`, but you cannot traverse the `iterator` in reverse order without making a copy(`ListIterator` supports reverse iteration though), but the closest you can get is to use `Array<T>` instead specific Array like below

```
 fun <T> Array<T>.forEachReversed(action: (T) -> Unit){
    for(i in indices.reversed()){  action(this[i]) }
 }
 
 val intArray = Array(2){ 0 }
 val longArray = Array<Long>(2){ 0 }
 intArray.forEachReversed { }
 longArray.forEachReversed {  }
```

Comment: Adding for T isn't a big deal. It's just one method for every other class. The question was if there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ajan.kali if you need primitive arrays there is not much you can do. I suppose you have to deal with arrays but, if this is not the case, you should prefer other data structures (more info [here](https://twitter.com/relizarov/status/1313475595892912134?s=20))
Returning to your question, if your are fine using generic arrays you could probably declare your iterator to iterate in reverse order:

```
class ReverseIterator<T>(val it: Iterable<T>) : Iterator<T> {
   private var index = it.count() - 1 
   override fun hasNext() = index >= 0  
   override fun next(): T = try { it.elementAt(index--) } catch (e: 
   IndexOutOfBoundsException) { index -= 1; throw 
     NoSuchElementException(e.message) }
}
```

then your extension function will become:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachReversed(action: (T) -> Unit) {   
   for(elem in ReverseIterator(this)) {
      action(elem)
   }
}
```

and then given an array you can invoke it this way:

```
intArrayOf(1, 2, 3).asIterable().forEachReversed { 
  println(it)
}
```

Not particularly happy with this, but with arrays there is not much you can do other to try avoiding them.